# Elihu (who helped Job) is Yitzhak?

Tags: midrash, talmud-yerushalmi, job-iyov-book-of, tractate-sotah

In the [Yerushalmi Sotah (5:8)](https://books.google.com/books?id=wxNWA7hwVYMC&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=elihu+ben+ram&source=bl&ots=F6u8lf27vN&sig=20lxMIEN47sd8OnkTeA5oljQFvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MkekVJTuOsSZNtDSgqgF&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=elihu%20ben%20ram&f=false) it says that Elihu ben Berachel was Yitzhak Avinu, who was niftar according to my calculations 10 years before Yaacov + fam descended to Egypt, which was around 93-94 years before the slavery started. So, if Iyov's punishment in the Book of Job was the suffering discussed in [Sotah 11a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=11&format=pdf) for keeping silent while advising Pharoah,  how could he have ever met Isaac?

Answer (score 7):

There are many different opinions as to when to place the book of Job.

The opinion that Elihu is Yitzhak is different from the opinion that he was an advisor to Pharaoh.

Comment: Citation needed for your first paragraph. (I think it's _Bava Basra_ 15 or so.)